# reduce from 12 to 7.5 volts and can carry 4 ampere

Tags: voltage, servo

i have 2 servos operating at 7.5  which each of them consume 4 ampere at stall and i have battery 12 volts.i want to make a circuit, buy a circuit or even know if it i possible to make or buy something to reduce 12 to 7.5 or 8.5 even (it is the same for me) and can carry 4 ampere without burning it. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think "7.5 or 8.5 even" is the desired voltage? What kind of servo's are those anyway? You'll probably end up looking for a switched mode power supply aka. a buck converter.

Comment: because i have 8.5 battery .......servo keep working until 7.5 (the servo can move at 7.5 but can't carry things ..i think the reason is leakage of enough ampere ) and the switched .... i don't know what is that.

Comment: What are the Servos? Usually they are rated to a certain voltage. Like 5-7V. If it needs 7.5V to move anything then your servos are under-sized. But it's hard to tell because you do not tell us all the details. You can get a ~10-15A supply for whatever voltage you want, just look online.

Comment: If you are using a 12V battery, and want at least 4A per servo, then one of these for each servo is perfect, and cheap: http://hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__49470__Quanum_12V_5A_7_2_25_2V_Dual_Output_UBEC.html

Answer (score 1):

The [L296 from STMicroelectronics](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000062.pdf) has the following specs:

```
Voltage - Input (Min)   9V
Voltage - Input (Max)   46V
Voltage - Output (Min)  5.1V
Voltage - Output (Max)  40V
Current - Output    4A
```

which appears to meet your needs.  [Available at Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/L296/497-2939-5-ND/634703) for $5.60.